# Nginx as a WebDAV server

Tags: nginx, webdav, synchronization

I want to syncronise some of my applications across my server, because I do not really like to register on every service I use.

I am using Nginx now, because I can do much-much more with that than Apache2, but as I see Nginx does not support WebDAV officially and I did not find any good solutions for it in Google and my favourite DuckDuckGo.

Do you guys have any experience with Nginx and WebDAV?
If yes, in which direction should I start?

Answer (score 1):

Nginx does support WebDAV (see also http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_dav_module.html) you have to build nginx from source and enable the the module with `./configure --with-http_dav_module ...`.